# phpMyadmin Query Execution Time

Tags: mysql

I tried to run the following query in my Cloud VPS cPanel phpMyadmin

```
SELECT bankcode, bankname 
FROM newbankdetails 
WHERE 
    type='DB' AND
    bankcode IN ( SELECT drawingbankname 
                  FROM dd1 
                  WHERE entrydate BETWEEN '01/04/2014' AND '30/04/2014' 
                    AND paymentmode='DD' 
                    AND state='TAMIL NADU' )
```

It takes very very very long time nearly 5 to 6 hours and says out of time or keeps running for days and don't show any error also don't show results.

Whereas it works perfectly in my local machine xampp

It happens only when working on large size tables like 12GB and around like that

How to speed it up and display the result as it displays instantly in localhost xampp

Comment: Is the `entrydate` column of type `varchar`?

Comment: Always remember try to avoid used of subquery. Subquery takes more time for execution.

Comment: @Ravinder It's char(10)

Comment: @facebook-1093767019 it's not char(10) it's varchar on dd1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, replacing `IN` with a `LEFT JOIN` can make more sense, like this:

```
SELECT 
    bankcode, bankname 
FROM 
    newbankdetails nd
    LEFT JOIN
    dd1 ON nd.bankcode = dd1.drawingbankname
WHERE 
    nd.type='DB' 
    AND
    dd1.entrydate BETWEEN '01/04/2014' AND '30/04/2014' 
    AND 
    dd1.paymentmode = 'DD' 
    AND 
    dd1.state = 'TAMIL NADU'
```

I can't test it, But I think with `dd1.paymentmode = 'DD'` automatically removes rows of `dd1.paymentmode IS NULL` because of using `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks now 6 hours execution time reduced to 4 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

First you should use EXPLAIN QUERY (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

That will give you information about what is slow.

Your problem seems to be related to the size of the table. On your localhost you may have a small table, but in production it is very large. Also put an index on the first table on nd.bankcode.

You should try to remove the subselect, and use a JOIN instead.

Also, you should put indexes on the columns you use for search.

---

Put an index on drawingbankname, entrydate, paymentmode, state. Put also an index on nd.backcode .
Column drawingbankname is varchar, you should convert it to fixed char.

Remove the subselect and use JOIN.

Use EXPLAIN after the changes to see progress.

Comment: If i use Join it of course reduces time but only reduces in few min like if it normal takes 6 hours for subselect it executes in 5 hours for JOIN , how to return result instantly as in localhost xampp

Comment: It depends. What is the size of the table in localhost? Sometimes the query time grows exponantial with the size of the table. Also, post the structure of your table and the indexes that you have.

Comment: Explain Query Result is as follows

http://s21.postimg.org/jydn0rkyf/Screen_Shot_2015_04_28_at_5_10_39_pm.png

Comment: Also, check configuration on server:  how much memory you have, size of query cache, innodb buffer size, etc. and compare with localhost

Comment: Structure:

http://s8.postimg.org/8tapop56d/Screen_Shot_2015_04_28_at_5_15_33_pm.png

Index :

http://s30.postimg.org/46jjgn5kx/Screen_Shot_2015_04_28_at_5_10_39_pm.png